# Reading two files into vectors First while loop works but second only iterates once?

Tags: c++

Is there a function that I am supposed to be using before I start reading from another file? I used File1.close but that hasn't helped and my second while loop which reads from (File2 >> a) only iterates one time. I'm not sure how to fix this. The console output only has the first value from my file and then stops. The files I am reading into my vector are in their correct locations where my project is stored. What did I do wrong?

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    vector<int> EmpId1, EmpId2, hours;
    vector<double> Payrate, Paycheck;
    ifstream File1, File2;
    ofstream PayRoll("PayRoll.txt");

    // Open the file
    File1.open("HoursWorked.txt");
    if (!File1)
    {
        cout << "The file was not found." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Read and print every word already in the file   
    while (File1 >> a)
    {
        EmpId1.push_back(a);
        File1 >> a;
        hours.push_back(a); 
    }

    for (unsigned int count = 0; count < EmpId1.size(); count++)
    {
        cout << EmpId1[count] << "***1****" << hours[count] << endl;
    }

    // Clear end of file flag to allow additional file operations
    File1.clear();
    File1.close();
        //Close if file cannot be found
    File2.open("HourlyRate.txt");
    if (!File2)
    {
        cout << "The file was not found." << endl;
        return 1;`enter code here`
    }

    // Read and print every word already in the file 
    while (File2 >> a)
    {
        EmpId2.push_back(a);
        File2 >> a;
        Payrate.push_back(a);
    }

    for (unsigned int count = 0; count < EmpId2.size(); count++)
    {
        cout << EmpId2[count] << "****2***" << Payrate[count] << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `Payrate` is a vector of `double`.
In order to provide it with a new value to be stored, you use `File >> a`.
But the variable `a` has type `int`; if the content of `File2` at this point is `12.34` for example, then only `12` will be extracted in order to initialise `a`.
This integer value is silently converted to `double` and stored in `Payrate`.

At this point, the remaining of `File2` starts with `.34`.
The next iteration, tries again to extract an integer in order to place it in `EmpId2`.
But this **fails** because an integer cannot start with the character `.`, thus the second `while` loop stops.

Comment: Good catch... On the other hand: using `double` for this purpose might not be best idea anyway, we always rely on rounding (not even simple `0.2` can be represented exactly...). I'd prefer fixed point integer arithmetic for this purpose, e. g. specifying all values as cents...

Comment: @Aconcagua you are right. Nevertheless I don't think the OP's question is already concerned by such subtle behaviour of the floating point representation.

Comment: @prog-fh Wow, I can't believe I missed that. I got it working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

They are two independent files, so you even could keep open both at the same time...

I'd rather assume that the second file is not valid. You might want to check *after* the while loop:

```
if(!fileX.eof())
{
    // if you did not reach the end of the file, something must have gone wrong,
    // so you could report the error
}
```

If you want to have more fine grained control over what went wrong:

```
for(;;)
{
    fileX >> a;
    if(!fileX)
    {
        // assuming reaching end of file is fine!
        if(!fileX.eof())
        {
            // report some error (invalid file format?);
        }
        break;
    }
    fileX >> a;
    if(!fileX)
    {
        // report error
        break;
    }
```